# SQL: Search for specific customer who have specific domian in their email address

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I have a table which contains customer's info. I wanted to select only those customer who have below domain in their email address. How can I do that?

Domain such as

```
aol.com
gmail.com
yahoo.com
msn.com
```

How can I make a select query with where clause?

For Example:

```
select ID, FirstName, LastName from Customer_Info where Email like '%gmail.com'
```

I can't create like if I have many domain. So please suggect if any other option is available

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to ignore "like" for such query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CI.CustomerID ,
       CI.FirstName,
       CI.LastName,
From Customer_Info CI with (nolock)
WHERE   SUBSTRING(Email,PATINDEX('%@%',Email)+1,100) IN ('aol.com','gmai.com','yahoo.com','msn.com')
```